# Images belonging to FeedWordpress imports are resized - but where?

Tags: php, wordpress, rss

I'm using FeedWordpress to import news to the newsroll of a mother company from a subsidiary webpage.

The RSS-excerpt for a specific item can be seen here: [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/zZ7tuttd)

As you can see, I'm getting the images I need into the RSS-file, into the start of the description block, as well as the content:encoded block:

```
<img
  width="2400" 
  height="1350" 
  src="http://shh.local:8888/content/uploads/2015/10/Skogskullen-2-01.jpg"
  class="attachment-full wp-post-image" 
  alt="Skogskullen 2 01 nyheter"
/>
```

FeedWordpress correctly parses the image and finds it. It's very weird though, because what gets imported is that same image, but resized with the "-150x150" flag. The original is nowhere to be seen.

I desperately need the import to work with the original image resolution. I've looked through the source for the plugins, but I can't for the life of me find any mention of 150x150.

I'm the sole developer of both sites, so I can work with both code bases. I'd appreciate any help or tips to what I can look at to figure this out.

Comment: hi, do you have your feed location and template being used to render the posts?

Comment: Similar to David's question, what are you doing with the feed data coming in?  Is FeedWordpress importing the images into your media library, is it rendering the data directly into the post (or page, etc) template, or something else? I'm wondering because many themes use the_post_thumbnail() for displaying featured images, and that could be defaulting to the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail') which would be 150x150 by default in WP.

Comment: Have you check the feed image is uploaded with original size in "wp-content/uploads" directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use FeedPress for an intranet website and I can reassure you that it won't tamper with image sizes. This strongly suggests that your templateing or another plugin does the image resizing.

Original images should be stored in folder `wp-content/uploads`.

Comment: Thanks @maxhb, I wouldn't normally say that your answer qualified as a solution but it led me to the right track. Since the site I worked on now initially was a fork of the old site I had a lot of the uploads from that site left in uploads. I deleted them and voila - The import worked fine!